# Texture turning black instead of showing 2D Perlin Noise

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, perlin-noise

I'm trying to learn more about programming with Unity, so I have been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WP-Bm65Q-1Y&list=PLFt_AvWsXl0eBW2EiBtl_sxmDtSgZBxB3&index=2) about Perlin Noise terrain generation.

I have followed along and checked my work, but for whatever reason when I try to generate the noise the texture of the plane it is being applied to turns black.

My code is exactly the same as [his code](https://github.com/SebLague/Procedural-Landmass-Generation/tree/master/Proc%20Gen%20E02/Assets/Scripts) and I followed along with every else done in Unity.

The only difference between my project and his is that mine has the default `Main Camera` and `Directional Light` object. As far as I can tell those don't make a difference.

It would be great to know if anyone else has dealt with a similar issue and knows what might be causing it.

Answer (score 0):

An friend of mine once had the same problem. When I remember Correctly it appears whenever you have negative values in your Perlin Noise generation so you should check for Negative values in your script. Otherwise it could might be a problem with your Unity version did you compare the used unity version from the tutorial with yours ?